# Arrow down and right icon in HUD

Tags: warframe

What does the blue arrow icon pointing down to the right represent, with the 10%?
[image: Arrow in HUD]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [this page](https://semlar.com/buffs), that symbol is for Affinity Spike.

[image: buff]

From [the Wiki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Naramon), this seems to appear when:

> Kills from melee attacks grant 10% / 15% / 20% / 25% / 35% / 45% more affinity.
>
> - Activates on calling out the Operator. Lasts throughout the duration of the mission.

The appears to be part of the Naramon school.  Reading the [Focus 2.0 page](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Focus#Naramon), you select a Tenno School after the Second Dream quest.  I assume this is the school you've selected.